# Character.forDigit always returns null

Tags: java

Given a character, I intend to know if it's a hexadecimal character. From various forums, I understand we can achieve it from `Integer` class as well. But wondering what is wrong in the below code.

```
Character.forDigit('C',16)
```

As per [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit(int,%20int)), for the above code the null character (`'\u0000'`) is returned if its not a valid hexadecimal character. Please point out what is wrong. Is the radix wrong? I verified with snippet of code:

```
if(Character.forDigit('C',16) == '\u0000') {
    System.out.println("Invalid Character");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [Character.digit(char ch, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29).

```
if (Character.digit('C',16) == -1) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Character");
}
```

`Character.forDigit()` works the other way around, like others have already pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

No, the way you use it is incorrect.
Try this:
`Character.forDigit(12,16)`
and you'll see what's wrong.

See also:

[Character.forDigit(int,int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

`Character.forDigit(int, int)` takes an int and returns the according char, not the other way around, as you are doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Hexadecimal characters represents in Java with '0x' prefix. so, your validation code always returns as "invalid character".

Try use with prefix. 
for ex:

```
if(Character.forDigit(0xC,16)=='\u0000'){
            System.out.println("Invalid Character");
}
```